# vsearch - clulstering with multi-threading

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

I have several fasta files that I want to cluster using vsearch (https://github.com/torognes/vsearch) and save a *"centroid file"* and *"clustering-results file"* for each fasta file.

Since I have many files, I plan to utilise the multithreading capabilities of vsearch and I wrote the loop below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# input fasta files
fastaFile=*.fasta

# vsearch cluster_fast loop
for f in $fastaFile
do
    vsearch --cluster_fast \
    $f \
    --id 1 \
    --qmask none \
    --centroids $f.$centroids.txt \
    --uc $f.uc.txt
done
```

Unfortunately, It appears multithreading is used on each fasta file at a time and I cannot figure out how to organize the parallelisation outside of vsearch.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/GNU-Parallel.html), or this thread on [Parallelize a Bash FOR Loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103920/parallelize-a-bash-for-loop).

Comment: Thanks @Jens..I'll have a look a it